# The best practices to to create global variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, global-variables

I'm working on IOS Static Library.
I need to create global variable accessible only in this library.
I knew 3 ways to do it

The question is, which way better to do it.

---

First solution: **SharedInstance**

.h:

```
  @interface GlobalVars : NSObject
    @property  int counter;
    +(instancetype)sharedInstance;
@end
```

.m:

```
 @implementation GlobalVars
    +(instancetype)sharedInstance {

        static dispatch_once_t p = 0;
        __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
        dispatch_once(&p, ^{
            _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
        });
        return _sharedObject;
    }

    +(int)counter{
    return [GlobalVars sharedInstance].counter;
    }

    +(void)setCounter:(int)_counter{
    [GlobalVars sharedInstance].counter=_counter;
    }
@end
```

using in code:

```
  [GlobalVars setCounter:5];
    int i= GlobalVars.counter
```

---

Second solution:  **static variable+class methods**

h:

```
 @interface GlobalVars
 + (int) counter;
 + (void) setCounter:(int)val;
 @end
```

m:

```
 @implementation GlobalVars
 static int value;
+ (int) counter {   
 return value;
   }

+ (void) setCounter:(int)val {
 value = val; 
 }
     @end
```

using in code:

```
   [GlobalVars setCounter:5];
    int i= GlobalVars.counter
```

---

Third solution:  **extern variable**

Constants.h:

```
extern int *kCounter ;
```

using in code:

```
#import "Constants.h"
-(void)someMethod{
kCounter=5;
int i=kCounter;
}
```

Thanks

edit:
The solution must be "Thread Safe"

Answer (score 1):

For most types you may use `NSUserDefaults`. In AppDelegate you can register default values and later modify them from any scope.

### [Example](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)

Saving

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// saving an NSInteger
[prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"integerKey"];

// saving a Double
[prefs setDouble:3.1415 forKey:@"doubleKey"];

// saving a Float
[prefs setFloat:1.2345678 forKey:@"floatKey"];

// This is suggested to synch prefs, but is not needed (I didn't put it in my tut)
[prefs synchronize];
```

Retrieving

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// getting an NSInteger
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];

// getting an Float
float myFloat = [prefs floatForKey:@"floatKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Singelton design pattern to create global variable, since you can use through out class with single instance and in future, if you want some more global variable then you can use same Singelton class.so i think your first approach is better.

However, If you think you will only use 1 or 2 variable as global then your 3rd approach is right.

Comment: Placing the code outside a class, makes it less reusable?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best solution is, to have no global. And this is possible always. You should really recheck the need.

*You have done this and still need a global var.*

Please, rerecheck that.

*You have done this and still need a global var.*

If you have to have that thread safe, it is quite clear that you need a piece of code to make it thread safe. Therefore the last variant – directly accessing the global var – cannot work. But you can still use a global variable, but have to add functions to access it. You can do that easily in plain C (Surprise? Doesn't have C developers the same problem every day?) and I would prefer this, because the global var is no object state. So way using an object? (Classes are *no* modules. They are construction plans for objects.)

Here we go:

something.h

```
void setCounter( int counter );
int getCounter( void );
```

something.c (or .m)

```
static int counter; // The asterik * is a typo?

void setCounter( int newCounter )
{
   // Do something for being thread safe, i. e. locking or GCD
   counter = newCounter;
}

int getCounter( void )
{
   // Do something for being thread safe, i. e. locking or GCD
   return counter;
}
```